# Networking conflict - What is the most common default computer name for Windows?

Tags: windows, networking

I recently had to change the name of my computer to log onto a public wi-fi spot, because a computer with my name was already logged on. (I asked a guy there what to do after it said there was already a computer named "(omitted)" logged on.)  I've never been at a wifi spot you had to log into before. I didn't even notice what the computer's name was before.

My question is what are the most common default computer names.  I'm curious.  How often does this sort of problem happen?

Thanks.

Comment: don't close this one; the user has crossposted but this one has answers already.

Answer (score 2):

Probably: Home,HomeComputer,Notebook,Laptop,PC,MyPC,Computer,<\YourName>-Computer etc.

Or maybe : AssetNo.761238129ER

Default Computer Name when installing Windows is pretty complicated so we can't blame Microsoft. (although why not, let's do it!)

Trivia:
http://www.whatsmypass.com/the-top-500-worst-passwords-of-all-time
and
http://modernl.com/article/top-10-most-common-passwords

Comment: Thanks.  The trivia is of the type I'm looking for.  Somebody probably keeps those statistics.

Comment: 'owner' is another common one

Comment: because it is so common, some people are against the .home tld: http://icannwiki.com/.home

Answer (score 0):

There is no good answer for the question you're asking. Windows doesn't have any common default computer names. Each vendor can make up their own. Taking a wild-ass guess, I imagine that the most common names are "home" and "computer" and "laptop". The most common naming *scheme* that I've seen in corporations makes the computer name related to either the serial number or the asset tag - the former should be globally unique, the latter might not be.

If you have a known example, that of your own computer name, why don't you include it in this question?

To solve the problem, why don't you try to name it something obscure? Your first initial, last name, and then a random number? Of course, since your first name is John, if your last name is Smith, that's still risking a lot of collisions.

Comment: My name was the computer manufacturer's name and then some numbers.  I read that Redhat linux defaults to "localhost," and all Toshiba laptops default to "Toshiba."

Comment: Well, an answer for what Redhat does wouldn't really apply, since your tags include Windows and don't include Linux.

However, for your described scenario, a commercial hotspot environment should really either not care about what the hostnames are, or be able to deal with collisions.